# i made a function and then i used the same code that is in the function to get the minimum value through a for loop but i am getting different answers

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

the function is to calculate cost based on earning, loan taken, fees, rates and duration, but when applying the exact same code that is there in the function to a for loop the answers are coming different, can help me out as i am new to programming

```
#income tax calculation and cost calc
# earning, loan y n, interest rate, years, fees

def IT_calc(earn,l,ir,d,f):
    interest_payable = f * ir * d
    amount_payable = f + interest_payable
    if l == 0:
        if earn <= 250000:
            income_tax = 0
        elif earn <= 500000:
            income_tax = (earn-250000)*0.05
        elif earn <= 750000:
            income_tax = (250000*0.05)+ (earn-500000)*0.10
        elif earn <= 1000000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10) + (earn-750000)*0.15
        elif earn <= 1250000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15) + (earn-1000000)*0.20
        elif earn <= 1500000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20) + (earn-1250000)*0.25
        else:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20+0.25) + (earn-1500000)*0.30
        cost = (income_tax * 1.04 * d) + f
        print('Your total cost over', d, 'years without loan is:', cost)
    else:
        earn = earn-(amount_payable//d)
        if earn <= 250000:
            income_tax = 0
        elif earn <= 500000:
            income_tax = (earn-250000)*0.05
        elif earn <= 750000:
            income_tax = (250000*0.05)+ (earn-500000)*0.10
        elif earn <= 1000000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10) + (earn-750000)*0.15
        elif earn <= 1250000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15) + (earn-1000000)*0.20
        elif earn <= 1500000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20) + (earn-1250000)*0.25
        else:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20+0.25) + (earn-1500000)*0.30
        cost = (income_tax * 1.04 * d) + amount_payable
        print('Your total cost over', d, 'years with loan is:', cost)

IT_calc(1200000,1,0.085,3,1600000)
>> Your total cost over 3 years with loan is: 2056568.104


#For loop
b = []
f = 1600000
ir = 0.085
earn = 1200000
l = 1
for t in range(1,20):
    interest_payable = f * ir * t
    amount_payable = f + interest_payable
    if l == 0:
        if earn <= 250000:
            income_tax = 0
        elif earn <= 500000:
            income_tax = (earn-250000)*0.05
        elif earn <= 750000:
            income_tax = (250000*0.05)+ (earn-500000)*0.10
        elif earn <= 1000000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10) + (earn-750000)*0.15
        elif earn <= 1250000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15) + (earn-1000000)*0.20
        elif earn <= 1500000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20) + (earn-1250000)*0.25
        else:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20+0.25) + (earn-1500000)*0.30
        cost = (income_tax * 1.04 * t) + f
    else:
        earn = earn-(amount_payable//t)
        if earn <= 250000:
            income_tax = 0
        elif earn <= 500000:
            income_tax = (earn-250000)*0.05
        elif earn <= 750000:
            income_tax = (250000*0.05)+ (earn-500000)*0.10
        elif earn <= 1000000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10) + (earn-750000)*0.15
        elif earn <= 1250000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15) + (earn-1000000)*0.20
        elif earn <= 1500000:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20) + (earn-1250000)*0.25
        else:
            income_tax = (250000)*(0.05+0.10+0.15+0.20+0.25) + (earn-1500000)*0.30
        cost = (income_tax * 1.04 * t) + amount_payable
    b.append(cost)

b
>>[1736000.0,
 1872000.0,
 2008000.0,
 2144000.0,
 2280000.0,
 2416000.0,
 2552000.0,
 2688000.0,
 2824000.0,
 2960000.0,
 3096000.0,
 3232000.0,
 3368000.0,
 3504000.0,
 3640000.0,
 3776000.0,
 3912000.0,
 4048000.0,
 4184000.0]
```

i was trying to estimate the minimum costs but i am getting the wrong answer through the for loop, am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure how the two outputs are related.  The function produces a single value output, but the loop produces a list with 20 values.  How are those outputs the same?  Is one of those 20 values supposed to be the same as the single function output?  If so, which one?

Comment: Why didn't you just call your calculator in the loop? `for d in range(1,20): IT_calc(earn,l,ir,d,f):`. Also, isn't the a formula for this that doesn't involve 20 conditions?

Answer (score 1):

In your for loop, you are changing the value of `earn` on every loop with the line `earn = earn-(amount_payable//t)`, so that it is not starting at 1200000 for each case.

Either reset it inside the for loop, or as OneMadGypsy suggests, change the IT_calc function to return the value instead of printing and use it in your for loop instead of having a slightly modified copy of the entire function.